# Show that $a^1,a^2,a^3,\ldots$ is not bounded from above for $a>1$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, proof-verification

I want to **prove** that the sequence $a^1,a^2,a^3,\ldots$ is not bounded from above for $a>1$?

---

For any $a>1$ we can always find $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $a>1+\frac{1}{n}$ and
$$a^n>\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n >2$$

$$a^{n} a^{n}>\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n} \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n} >2\cdot 2$$

$$a^{n} a^{n} a^{n}>\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n} \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n} \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n}>2\cdot 2 \cdot 2$$
$$\ldots$$

So clearly our sequence is not bounded from above.

Comment: @Solitary: What do you mean? He states that it is given that $a > 1$. His $n$ is given by the archimedean property of reals.

Comment: sorry, the OP is right, I deleted my comment.

Comment: @Solitary: Sure it's okay. Note also that your solution uses the archimedean property, although right at the end instead of at the start, when you say "clearly unbounded".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your way is reasonable, but uses Bernoulli's inequality. There is another more direct way.

If the sequence is bounded from above, it has a supremum $c$ by the completeness axiom for reals, and by definition we have $a^k > c/a$ for some natural number $k$ because $c/a < c$ since $a > 1$. Thus $a^{k+1} > c$, contradicting the choice of $c$.

Therefore the sequence is not bounded from above.

Comment: Fast & easy, thanks!

Comment: Fast and easy but using completeness, which is much more than necessary The OPs original proof is correct (and clever).

Comment: @luka5z: You're welcome. Note that this method is very general and works for all the basic sequences such as $a^n$ for $a < 1$ and $a^{1/n}$ for $a>0$.

Comment: @EthanBolker: You're completely mistaken. The archimedean property is of the same type as the completeness axiom.

Comment: Really? The rationals are archimedean but not complete.

Comment: @EthanBolker: Sure, that's why I didn't say equivalent. But it's the same type, and either way the completeness axiom is built into the structure of the reals unless you're using an axiomatization. Might as well get grips with the full structure. Even with an axiomatization, how would you prove the archimedean property of the reals? There is no way without the completeness axiom, because there are non-standard models of the (first-order) reals (the real-closed field axioms, missing completeness which is a second-order property).

Comment: I think archimedean is historically earlier (i.e. Euclid) and pedagogically and psychologically more appropriate for this question than complete (without getting into the formal logic, where you make good points). No need to argue further about it.

Answer (score 4):

Since $a > 1$, we can write $a = 1 + \delta$ for some $\delta > 0$, by binomial formula, for each $n$, 
$$a^n = (1 + \delta)^n = 1 + n\delta + \cdots + \delta^n > 1 + n\delta.$$
Since $\{n\delta\}$ is unbounded (for fixed $\delta$) by Archimedean property of real numbers, the result follows.

Answer (score 1):

This is another approach which uses proof by contradiction. Suppose that the sequence $s_{n} = a^{n}$ is bounded above. Since $a > 1$ we can see that $$s_{n + 1} = a^{n + 1} = a\cdot a^{n} = as_{n} > s_{n}$$ so that the sequence $s_{n}$ is strictly increasing. Since it is also bounded above it follows that the limit $L = \lim_{n \to \infty}s_{n}$ exists. Moreover because of strictly increasing nature $L$ must be greater than any term in the sequence. In particular $L > a > 1$. Since $s_{n + 1} = as_{n}$ it follows by taking limits that $L = aL$. However this is not possible if both $a , L $ are greater than $1$. This contradiction finishes our job and $s_{n} = a^{n}$ is unbounded.